# Copy ami to different region with cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am trying to copy an ami from one region to a different region through the AWS CLI.

The following command works fine for copying an ami to the *same* region:

```
aws ec2 copy-image --name ami-copy-test --source-image-id ami-123... --source-region us-east-1
```

but I am trying to copy to a *different* region, us-east-2 for instance.

---

There doesn't seem to be a `--destination-region` flag. The documentation page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-image.html
states:

> You specify the destination Region by using its endpoint when making
>   the request.

But what does this actually mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right page, just continue to read

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/copy-image.html
...
This example copies the specified AMI from the *us-east-1 region* to the *ap-northeast-1* region.

Command:

```
aws ec2 copy-image --source-image-id ami-5731123e --source-region us-east-1 --region ap-northeast-1 --name "My server"
```

Comment: Uhm, thanks! Not sure how I missed that... to my defense, the **--region** option does not seem to be listed for some reason